# Match part of url with regex

Tags: regex

I have a challenge with a regex match to a url I hope I can bug some of you clever heads with :-)

Please take a look at this testcase https://www.regex101.com/r/bH4hE1/2

I use the regex: (\w+)(.\w+)+(?!.*(\w+)(.\w+)+)

Problem is, it only finds reports.html but I also need to find reports in the first url

https://my.website.com/reports?ref_=kdp_BS

https://my.website.com/reports.html

Comment: Which **parts** are you trying to extract? What **language**?

Comment: what do you looking for? `reports?` or `reports?ref_=kdp_BS`

Comment: I'm looking for reports in first url and reports.html in second case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To capture "reports" or "reports.html" in any path, begin your match after the last `/`, and capture word characters and `.`:

```
/.*\/([.\w+]+)/
```

See: https://www.regex101.com/r/iZ7dF3/8

Comment: From your example I just need the 3'rd capturing group. Please forgive my ignorance, but how would get just that?

Comment: If you don't need to capture the rest, just remove the parens, or change to non-capturing groups (?:.+). I'll update the answer to capture only the relevant part.

Comment: Ahh man... just when I thought all was perfect. When I add a subfolder into the mix, it messes things up. Do you have an idea about that? See https://www.regex101.com/r/iZ7dF3/6

Comment: Updated it to grab "reports.*" regardless of path.

Comment: I feel like the stupid boy in class :-D
Must be language but when I load the regex into my software it captures all in blue from regex101 e.g.: https://my.website.com/reports? 
Do you have an idea?

Comment: Which language are you using? regex syntax can vary quite a bit

Comment: Well... I'm not quite sure :-D 
I use something called ubot studio - it builds on .net - my guess would be c#

Comment: I think it has more to do with the software than the regex. It is _matching_ everything and just disregarding the capture group. I'm sure the method you need to pull the value in the capture is documented somewhere...

Comment: You might be right... unfortunately there ain't much documentation but I see it grabs everything that regex101 marks on the test string...

Comment: http://www.ubotstudio.com/forum/index.php?/topic/11139-choose-specific-match-result-group/?hl=capture  has an example of loading matches into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/([^\/?]+)(?:\?.+)?$/gim
```

It will work end selects:

```
reports
reports.html
```

Comment: Close, but I have to remove the ?ref_=kdp_BS part as well